# Selecting a field from a Fusion Table

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-fusion-tables

I would like to select this row (it is a polygon) from this fusion table (called CDM_areas). I am struggling with the code to select such a field...

I have so far (uncertain in bold):

```js
var ndviclip = ndvichange.clip(CDM_areas.select('name' **= '40'**));
```

[image: Fusion Table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `FeatureCollection` has `Features` with one or many `properties`. When you call `select` on a `FeatureCollection` you'll get the same but each `Feature` will keep only the `properties` you have indicated in the `select` method. See this example:

```js
var geometry = ee.FeatureCollection(
        [ee.Feature(
            ee.Geometry.Point([-115.59062499999999, 39.72805832737948]),
            {
              "system:index": "0",
              "id": "0",
              "name": "zero"
            }),
        ee.Feature(
            ee.Geometry.Point([-104.25273437499999, 45.78644775647758]),
            {
              "system:index": "1",
              "id": "1",
              "name": "one"
            }),
        ee.Feature(
            ee.Geometry.Point([-91.50859374999999, 37.74005100886954]),
            {
              "system:index": "2",
              "id": "2",
              "name": "two"
            })]);

print(geometry.first())
print(geometry.select('name').first())
```

[image]

What you are looking for is to filter the `FeatureCollection` by `name`, and as you know `name` are unique, you get only the `Feature` you need.

```js
var myfeature = ee.Feature(CDM_areas.filterMetadata('name', 'equals', 40).first()); // If it is a string column you have to quote it: '40'
var ndviclip = ndvichange.clip(myfeature);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip Rodrigo, sadly it didn't work. I now imported the shapefile directly (no fusion table). The NEW_ID field is now the one I need to select a value from. I tried different values and different columns but no luck. It keeps returning 'null' in the Console. 

Code: 
var project1 = ee.Feature(CDM_areas.filterMetadata('NEW_ID', 'equals', '30').first());

Comment: Is "NEW_ID" a number column? If so, I guess it should be `project1 = ee.Feature(CDM_areas.filterMetadata('NEW_ID', 'equals', 30).first());`

Comment: Yes, that works. Thanks so much! Of course, it is not a string.
This is my first thread here... do I copy/ quote your answer in the "Answer Your Question" button?

Comment: I don't think your answer will be different of mine, because this is how you do it. I just didn't know if your column was a number or string, I supposed a string due to your first approach. I'll edit my answer